# How to access children component of an enyo kind?

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have a kind called RobustList, which extends `Control`, and it has these components:

```
components: [
    {name: "outerScroll",kind: "Scroller",touch: true,classes: "enyo-fit",components: [
            {name: "list",kind: "Repeater",onSetupItem: "setupItem",components: [
                    {name: "item",components: [
                            {name: "index",style: "display:none;"}
                    ]}, 
                    {name: "empty",fit: true,content: ""}, 
                    {name: "loadmore",fit: true,content: "Load More Items"}
                ]}
        ]}

]
```

Now I am catching the `onSetupItem` event, and in that function I am trying to access the children component. I am having a problem though. I was under the assumption that saying `this.$` gave me access to all of the children component. Its currently only giving me access to `outerscroll` and `list`. Why is that?

**Edit**

---

Ok so apparently when using the `List` kind I can access all the children components (specifically in the create enyo function I am overriding). I'm very confused as to when its appropriate to do certain things. Like I assumed `this.$` could be used everywhere. This is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question, yes, you can access any of the children of RobustList within the onSetupItem by using `this.$.` if it's a List.  Check the documentation here:  https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Lists . Because of its flyweight pattern there's only one active set of controls within the List so you can refer to them directly by name.

You wouldn't want to use `this.$.` to access the items in a Repeater because there are many copies of the components (one for each row). Use the passed in reference (e.g.  `var item = inEvent.item;`) to access the items within the row template.

I also notice you use 'fit: true' on a couple components  in the list.  You can only have one fit: true component in a FittableColumn/FittableRow.  Neither of those is actually in a fittable so it won't probably do what you want.

Comment: FWIW, List and Repeater can be confusing. The flyweight pattern does make some things tricky.

Comment: Oh, but I do have another question related to the passed in event variables. I need to use them in other situations that don't have the variables present. Changing it presented a problem so I hoped there was a better solution. It seems like its just the nature of the Repeater kind, but how can I access them all to style them after they have been set?

Comment: If you need to modify a row in a Repeater later you'll need to use `renderRow(inIndex)`

Comment: Another question if you wouldn't mind. I am having trouble with my repeater. On onSetupItem it seems to be returning null for item on all but the first one. I was under the assumption that it duplicated whats in repeater based on `count`. Could you explain how `Repeater` actually works and what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
setupItem:function(inSender,inEvent){
    var data = this.data;
    if(data){
        var item = inEvent.item;
        var row = data[inEvent.index];
        item.$.loadmore.set('content',row.content);
    }
},
```